# TypeScript - typesave mapping types of restricted tuple generic

Tags: typescript, generics, generic-constraints, keyof

In TypeScript this is not compiling:

```
export interface Generic<T extends string> {

}

export interface Class<T extends string[]> {
  readonly prop: { [P in keyof T]: Generic<T[P]> }
}
```

Particularly, the `Generic<T[P]>` fails with `Type 'T[P]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.`. However, since `T extends string[]`, it can be certain, that `T[P] extends string` for any `P in keyof T`.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

I know I can fix the problem with a conditional type:

```
export interface Class<T extends string[]> {
  readonly prop: { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? Generic<T[P]> : never }
}
```

But I don't see, why this should be necessary.

Comment: Isn't `P` can be `string`, `number` or `Symbol`?

Comment: @Anatoly yes, it can. I don't see your point though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the full error, the third line has a big clue:

```
Type 'T[P]' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2344)
```

The problem is that `keyof` any array type (or tuple type) will be more like `string | number | symbol`. And an array also has more than it's member type on those keys. For instance:

```
// (...items: string[]) => number
type PushFunction = string[]['push']
```

See this snippet. There's a lot more than just numbers in array keys:

```
// number | "0" | "1" | "2" | "length" | "toString"
// | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" | "concat"
// | "join" | "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort"
// | "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf"
// | ... 15 more ... | "includes"
type ArrayKeys = keyof [1,2,3]
```

And `Generic<T>` requires `T` to be a string, but, as shown, not all values of all keys of an array are strings.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAoDpoSwFwKYFsDOAuUK4CcYDsBzAbQF0BKUAXgD5Q8BXJAIwWwCg4BPABwVAAV6KABYAxengDGcGAHs8VTDnzESRAOTchw9STZsQdRi2ygAPqABEABkvmrARjsXLAJmdWANgkJxhHyzhZAGVlQksDMBcggBlZSQBDb1DccPtLblluAK0RAMl5RLgIwxcAK1l8AOwEADdWFAQAkRgAM2L0lE8YSSbO2WxiyM7ubt6AiRb2gPwAEwQADwB5VpKo0GhIUAcAVlAkAb5N9PxJT3p5lAiuXlAAQWxsBM4AaQROFEUAa3fZVtAiA4ADSuIEAZhIQA)

---

You can fix the mapped type very simply by intersecting the array keys with `number`, informing typescript that you only care about the number keys (which are the array indices):

```
export interface Generic<T extends string> {

}

export interface Class<T extends string[]> {
  readonly prop: { [P in keyof T & number]: Generic<T[P]> }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgcWCTQWwB4AVOUVJAEwGc4GYpkBzAPjgG8AoPgF8BoSLEQo0WXHADCAG0wMGlaiFqNmrDgG0Aut35w4UYJjoQk8gJ5wwUCGABcvODoAKEuAGtg1iOhwVABkcEgArgC2AEZoei6ExGzkFB4GcMLCfEA)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in TypeScript where the support (added in TS3.1) for [mapped types over tuples and arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) does not exist *inside* the implementation of such mapped types; see [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  It seems that [according to](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995#issuecomment-433056847) the lead architect of TypeScript:

> The issue here is that we only map to tuple and array types when we *instantiate* a generic homomorphic mapped type for a tuple or array (see [#26063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26063)).

So from the *outside*, when you *use* a mapped type on an array or tuple, the mapping preserves the array-or-tupleness of the input and only maps over numeric properties:

```
declare const foo: Class<["a", "b", "c"]>;
// (property) prop: [Generic<"a">, Generic<"b">, Generic<"c">]
const zero = foo.prop[0]; // Generic<"a">;
const one = foo.prop[1]; // Generic<"b">;
```

but on the *inside*, the compiler still sees `P in keyof T` as iterating over *every* key of `T`, including any possibly non-numeric ones.

```
export interface Class<T extends string[]> {
  readonly prop: { [P in keyof T]: Generic<T[P]> } // error!
}
```

---

As you note, there are workarounds for this, and these workarounds are mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#27995.  I think the best one is essentially the same as your conditional type:

```
export interface Class<T extends string[]> {
  readonly prop: { [P in keyof T]: Generic<Extract<T[P], string>> }
}
```

The other ones in there either don't work for generic types like `T`, or produce mapped types that are no longer true arrays or tuples (e.g., `{0: Generic<"a">, 1: Generic<"b">, 2: Generic<"c">}` instead of `[Generic<"a">, Generic<"b">, Generic<"c">]`... so I'll leave them out of this answer.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgcWCTQWwB4AVOUVJAEwGc4GYpkBzAPjgG8BYAFBw4AN0wAbAFxwKggL6DBoSLEQo0WXHADC4zAwaVqIWo2asOAbQC63fkLgB6R3CjBMdCEnEBPOGCgIMGkeOEsABTU4AGtgHwh0GWtpQmI2cgoI2zg5Jxc0QKgAQkFhNw8vX39A4N4wyOQYuISklKIScgBREygcGEosgBpzNiQubgUBScE6YGw9NzhsLxY4dAgIaV19Q0sAIkw94b2AIyO4Pew92wBuQWc4AAoAoLQYHwBKHT0DMn3D45nY5XWwAOhetUsqQ6ZAOe04w2h6VhZwRBHayMu8OsgmWSFWAC80BA4ABeNYbcE1SwABmsNzy6LSpFhh04dwEeNWXjw5PWECpQUsAEZ6YykSzTvCOUA)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for `T extends string[]`, `keyof T` includes not only numeric keys but also all methods form Array's prototype.
Proof? Here it is:

```
type StringArrayKeys = keyof string[];
// Produces: 
// type StringArrayKeys = number | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | 
//   "push" | "concat" | "join" | "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort" | "splice" | 
//   "unshift" | "indexOf"  | "lastIndexOf" | ... 16 more
```

So the easiest fix for Your example would be to replace `P in keyof T` with `P in number`:

```
export interface Generic<T extends string> {};

export interface Class<T extends string[]> {
    readonly prop: { [P in number]: Generic<T[P]> }
}
```